# More timers at same time in different threads

Tags: c#, .net, timer

```
bool elapsed = false;

private void timerElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)                
{
   elapsed = true;
}

private void WorkerThreadFunction()
{
    Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(60000);
    _timer.Elapsed += timerElapsed;
    _timer.AutoReset = false;

    while (!elapsed)
    {
         // Do something...
         Thread.Sleep(50);
    } 
}
```

How is the global variable "elapsed" reacting? Is it possible to run more separate WorkerThreads with timers?

Comment: What do you mean by "reacting"? Where's your problem with seperate WorkerThreads? Of course you can have more than one.

Comment: Yes, but what if timerElapsed sets the boolean variable true? How do the other WorkerThreads react? Is it still on 'false' there?

Comment: Of course not. You must make sure that every thread has its own "elapsed". Furthermore, read about `volatile`.

Comment: maybe ThreadLocal<> could help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The danger with this code is that the JIT might assume `elapsed` isn't being changed by the current thread in the loop and it might cache it in a CPU register thus it will never update. You either need to use `volatile` or some other inter-thread method of communication to ensure that this code will always work.

Comment: @xileb0 - Can you explain what you mean by "Is it possible to run more separate WorkerThreads with timers?"???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it is possible to run more separate WorkerThreads. Each one will have it's own timer. There shouldn't be a problem.

The variable `bool elapsed` will be set to true by the first `Thread` that finishes its job, and it will stay true until some other process sets it to false. If you are unlucky some thread might even not start its job because the first on has set your `elapsed` to `true`

EDIT:

it seems that your thread job is encapsulated. 
So you could actually also just use a stopwatch, if you don't need to access global variables from within the thread

```
private void WorkerThreadFunction()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();

    while(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 60000)
    {
         // Do something...
         Thread.Sleep(50);
    } 

    watch.Stop();
}
```

Comment: But I want, that the other Threads have their own "elapsed" variable. How can I do that?

Comment: Don't use a global variable

Comment: So I have to declare the elapsed variable in the Workerthread and then I have to pass it to the timerElapsed event?

Comment: @xileb0 I edited my answer. How would you pass the variable into the timerElapsed Event?

Comment: I have no idea, I like your solution. But would it be possible with a timer too?

Comment: This is a terrible solution - for two reasons: (1) you can't lock on a `bool` (as in `lock (elapsed)`), and (2) using a `Stopwatch` in a loop like that with a `Thread.Sleep` is terrible in that it locks up valuable system resources when a timer would be far preferable.

Comment: @Enigmativity So how would you do that?

Comment: @Enigmativity thank you for your comment. I removed the wrong part. I doubt that the OP would really want to use `Thread.Sleep(50);` in his code. It is probably to simulate some processing. This is why I used it from his example. I actually would also like to know how this problem could be solved using a timer. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @xileb0 - I don't see how this answer relates to your question. Can you explain in more detail what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @MongZhu - Even without the `Thread.Sleep` this isn't the way to program it. In fact, without the `Thread.Sleep` this is worse because then it will max the CPU out inside the loop.

Comment: I'd like to have more parallel WorkertThreads and everyone should have his own timerElapsed Event.

Comment: @xileb0 - Why? This sounds like an X-Y problem. What is it that you're actually trying to do?

Comment: @Enigmativity could you elaborate on "max the CPU out inside the loop" ? or point me to a direction where I can find more information. I tried google but up to now only get results that the Stopwatch method is not precise.

Comment: @MongZhu - If you run a tight loop over `while(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 60000) { ... }` then the CPU is working the whole time either computing within the `...` or it is checking if `watch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 60000` - so for 60 seconds it is working at 100%. If sleep the thread for portions of that time then you are freeing up the CPU, but you're still dedicating a thread to this one task. If you were to use timers, which is the right way to go, then you don't have any of these problems.

Comment: @Enigmativity thank you for the constructive criticism and for the enlightment. I will remember this for the future. So using a timer would save me checking if if-condition but how would it avoid the problem "CPU is working the whole time either computing within the `...`" ? I have a similar programm where I communicate with several devices via `SerialPort` for a certain amount of time in parallel.

Comment: Timers use appropriate calls to invoke a new thread as needed, so it doesn't tie up a thread doing nothing.